Source of the quote "I have most bitterly regretted that I didn’t study physics when I was at school," allegedly said by Doris Lessing
I have noticed that physicists have a tendency to reference this quote about the glamour of the science:

I have most bitterly regretted that I didn’t study physics when I was
at school, because it is the key to the most exciting research and
discoveries of our time, and physicists are the adventurers and the
risk takers. Young people who study physics can expect to find
themselves at the frontier of human thought.

and it is generally attributed to the Nobel prize-winner (and occasional science fiction author) Doris Lessing. Did Lessing actually say this, and if so, where is it from?

There are some other suspicious quotations in the Paul Strange list. For example, "Science is organised knowledge. Wisdom is organised life" is not from Kant himself, but from a summary of Kant by Will Durant.

@GarethRees The Thomas Watson quote is also rather dubious.

The academic I emailed wrote back and said he would add the word "attributed" to the quote.

I’ve found this scattered about the internet, but there seems to be no primary source. The closest I’ve come was a comment in Norwegian at calcuttagutta.com which gives as its source, “Quotation seen in E5 on the science(s) building.”
There is no case of this quote appearing anywhere in Google Books, which tells me that this is likely a spurious quote and not something that she ever said. Given that she’s been dead for over a decade, a definitive answer is probably impossible, but I would say that it’s likely not to be something she’s ever said. Whether she said anything like it or not, is open. The closest I’m aware of is her preface to The Sirian Experiments where she writes, “But we can’t all be physicists.”

Thanks for your effort. Yes, it's all over the internet, and proudly posted in many science departments (so I wouldn't put much confidence in the "Quotation seen in the science building"). Someone must have written it though!

@ClaraDíazSanchez I put no stock in it at all. I just thought it was amusing that this was the only case I could find of the quote being given any source.
